# Filter list into smaller lists depending on word

Tags: python, list

I have a list of reminders which changes depending on the day and it looks a bit like this:

```
reminders = ['homework friday', 'guitar lesson wednesday', 'piano monday',
             'gym wednesday', ...]
```

and I want to filter this into different lists depending on the weekday written in the string, so for example turn the list into these:

`friday = ['homework']`
`wednesday = ['guitar lesson', 'gym']`
`monday = ['piano']`

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: you should take a look at python [dictionaries](http://programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary).

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to implement a dictionary with nested lists like some of the other people in the comments suggested. But also show more of your work or at least what you tried so far next time:

```
todo = {
    'monday': [],
    'tuesday': [],
    'wednesday': [],
    'thursday': [],
    'friday': []
    }

unordered = ['homework-friday', 'guitar lesson-wednesday', 'piano-monday', 'gym-wednesday'] # maybe trying adding a delimiter for easier indexing
for key, value in todo.items():
    for x in unordered:
        if x[x.find("-")+1:] == key:
            value.append(x[:x.find("-")])
print(todo)
```